# Better performane of the Web Audio API on iOS in a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is there a way to get much better performane of the Web Audio API on iOS when using a UIWebView?

I've made an web app using the Web Audio API. It runs great on a desktop chrome browser but on iOS in a UIWebView it's quite slow. As we know javascripts is about 10 times more cpu consuming vs native code for similar results.

For example there is ways to get the HTML5 canvas Hardware-Accelerated on ios.. so is there anything similar for the web audio api i wonder.

Comment: If you want help optimizing some of your JavaScript or would like some input on more efficient ways to use the Web Audio API, I'm sure there are plenty of people who would love to help (myself included). But no, there's no magic bullet for making a UIWebView run your code faster.

Comment: Cool. I see. I will give some code example later on. For javascript html5 canvas I think there is kind of a magic bullet with Ejecta - Impact for example and some other more frameworks, perhaps phonegaps.. and I think there's some more. Thought it might be doable to get the web audio api code runned better on ios the same way somehow

Comment: You will get an +1 for your comment, thanks :)

Comment: To this date it's still slow compared even to Safari WKWebView. Did you file a bug report ?

Comment: Thanks for the ping, yes - please do a bug report. I haven't done so.